# Create a copy of a child gameObject and have it still exist when the parent is deleted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject

I have implemented an instantiation spawn system into my endless runner game. I want to have a gameObject inside a parent  gameOject to follow the player as far as it needs to and not disappear when the parent gameobject is called back in the pool.

- **what i really  need to do is, create a copy of a child gameObject and have it still exist when the parent is deleted.**

I don't know if this is possible. If not, point me where to go

Answer (score 2):

Well, You could either simply detach the child from the parent before it gets destroyed by simply changing its [`Transform.parent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

```
theChild.transform.parent = null; // or any other Transform
```

or you could create a clone of the child via [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) e.g

```
Instantiate(theChild, theChild.transform.position, theChild.transform.rotation);
```